# Difference between .NET MAUI Border and Frame

Tags: maui

What's the functional difference between a Border and a Frame in .NET MAUI?

The summary of a Border according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border) is

> The .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) Border is a container control that draws a border, background, or both, around another control. A Border can only contain one child object. If you want to put a border around multiple objects, wrap them in a container object such as a layout.

And the summary of a [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame) is as follows

> The .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) Frame class is used to wrap a view or layout with a border that can be configured with color, shadow, and other options. Frames can be used to create borders around controls but can also be used to create more complex UI.

Sounds like they both do the same thing to me: drawing a border around another view (whether that's a layout or a single control doesn't matter). So why are there 2 different views? How do I decide which one to use?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think this is due to the history of .NET MAUI. The `Frame` is a control that is in Xamarin.Forms. I'm not sure if it was ever intended to be *the* control to put a border around something, but since if was the only control that could do a shadow and border for a long time, a lot of people wrapped their controls in a `Frame`.

However, now with .NET MAUI there is the opportunity to fix some historical tech debt. That is why `Border` was introduced which is much more flexible. With `Border` you can give each corner an individual corner radius for instance. And instead of just a solid color you can give the `Border` a gradient.

So from a functional perspective the `Border` has more options and will probably outlive the `Frame` although there is no indication that `Frame` is going anywhere anytime soon.

There is probably more little differences here and there. Based on nothing more than a gut feeling I would think `Border` performs better, but I have no data to back that up.

Hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: So, is there any reason to use a Frame at all?

Comment: Other than if you have code that is written in Forms and you're transitioning to .NET MAUI? I would say no. If this helped, please don't forget to mark it as answer!

Comment: What about Shadow using `Border` ? I don't see how to add a shadow for a Border surrounding a Label for example.

Comment: Also I am not sure if you are able to add a Linear Gradient brush to the border control

Comment: There's definitely some behavior difference between `Frame` and `Border`. I don't know exactly why but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76047742/net-maui-xaml-adjust-text-and-frame-when-resizing/76047858#76047858) is an example.