# .Net MAUI Xaml - adjust text and frame when resizing

Tags: c#, maui

Have this code. The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out the text and frame to adjust when resizing my screen.

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- First block of text -->
        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Padding="10" Margin="10">
            <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor." />
        </Frame>

        <!-- Second block of text -->
        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGreen" Padding="10" Margin="10">
            <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor." />
        </Frame>

        <!-- Third block of text -->
        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightPink" Padding="10" Margin="10">
            <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor." />
        </Frame>

        <!-- More blocks of text... -->
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[Text not wrapping, not round edges when resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2uZE.png)

I want the text to wrap onto next lines and the background to have the same round edges on both sides.

Comment: How are you "resizing the screen"? Is this a user action, or programmatic? If programmatic, add that code to question. ScrollView has a `ContentSize`, which needs to be programmatically set when screen size changes. To give answer, need more details about the situation.

Comment: As I resize the screen manually, the `Label `inside `Frame` can resize automatically [Text wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp3tC.png). You may need to upgrade your Visual Studio to the latest version to see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know why `Frame` acts that way but switching `Frame` to `Border` works for me:

```xml
<!-- First block of text -->
<Border BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Padding="10" Margin="10" >
    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10" />
    </Border.StrokeShape>
                
    <Label LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor." />
</Border>
```

[image]

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71739057/653457, apparently `Border` is an improvement of `Frame` anyway. Also per [Frame documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame?view=net-maui-7.0):

> The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property on VisualElement. For more information, see Border and Shadow.

---

Also not in your question but you should use [`VerticalStackLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/verticalstacklayout?view=net-maui-7.0) (or the Horizontal version) instead of `StackLayout` for MAUI.

> The .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) VerticalStackLayout organizes child views in a one-dimensional vertical stack, and is a more performant alternative to a StackLayout.

Comment: The new Border control is recommended and preferred over Frame, which is legacy.

Comment: FWIW: *"You should use ..."*: When making a recommendation, please say **why** - what is the benefit? When does it matter? (In this case, docs say those variants are "more performant" than the generic StackLayout.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks I added it. Last night it was late and I was too lazy to look for the documentation URL lol.