# .NET-MAUI Controls not working after Deployment to iOS

Tags: maui, maui-ios

I was working with my .NET MAUI App mainly on *Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)*-Emulator and it was working fine so far.

Now came the reality check and I wanted to run it on iOS. I deployed it to *iOS 16.2*-Simulator. I was a bit shocked as no control can be clicked anymore, also my Sharpnado-Bottom-Toolbar could not be clicked to switch View, my Flyout-Item also did not display anything.

Regarding the Controls on my Main-View, they are within Frames. My Frames appear or look like they are in the Background regarding ZIndex, but I did not change anything and currently also don't know what I could change to get them to the foreground or what's wrong here so that they are displayed absolutely correct in Android Emulator but not on iOS Simulator

```
<Frame Grid.Row="1" BorderColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="Start"
HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="710" WidthRequest="365"
IsClippedToBounds="True" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="20"
Margin="15,-485,50,15" Padding="0"
BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" Opacity="0.9">
   ...
</Frame>
```

Comment: Not directly answering your question but `Frame` is there for backward compability. You should not use it anymore and [should use `Border` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame). Check this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76047858/653457

Comment: That's a good hint - I will try it then with Border and comment if it worked with this